# profile API call

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi, profiler

I enable profiler `SetEnv MAGE_PROFILER html` in my `conf file` for magento 2.

Is there an easy way to profile Magento 2 API REST calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to check (even as a trial option) solutions like:

- **Blackfire.io**
- **NewRelic**
- **xdebug**

Those tools will show you exact traces and timing of each separate PHP Trace that is involved within any operation/transaction (not limited to API calls)

For Database related bottlenecks - **[MySQL Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)** can be enabled (*depends on MySQL Version used). This can be used without mentioned performance monitoring tools

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to is add another strpos condition in `app/bootstrap.php` on `rest/V1`

```
if (
    (!empty($_SERVER['MAGE_PROFILER']) || file_exists(BP . '/var/profiler.flag'))
    && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])
    && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], 'text/html') !== false || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'rest/V1') !== false)
) {
```